# Valid format of ranges for vue2-daterange-picker

Tags: vuejs2, daterangepicker

Using vue2-daterange-picker I search how to hide left selection items, as 'Today','Yesterday',
'This month', 'This year', but I did fin valid format.

In the docs I found :

> default ranges object (set to false to hide ranges) {
>       'Today',
>       'Yesterday',
>       'This month',
>       'This year',
>       'Last week',
>       'Last month', }

making :

```
<date-range-picker
        :opens="date_range_picker_locale_opens"
        @update="updateValues"
        :singleDatePicker="true"
        :locale-data="dateRangePickerLocale"
        :autoApply="true"
        :ranges="defaultRanges"
        :show-dropdowns="false"
        :alwaysShowCalendars="false"
        v-model="ad_expire_date"
        class="form-control editable_field"
>
    <div slot="input" slot-scope="picker">
        {{ picker.startDate | date }}
    </div>
</date-range-picker>

...
defaultRanges: {  // I got a eslint syntax errors
'Today',
'Yesterday',
'This month',
'This year',
'Last week',
'Last month',
},
```

Which is valid format?

```
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"vue2-daterange-picker": "^0.4.4",
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valid decision was to set property to false :

```
<date-range-picker
        :opens="date_range_picker_locale_opens"
        @update="updateValues"
        :singleDatePicker="true"
        :locale-data="dateRangePickerLocale"
        :autoApply="true"
        :ranges="false"
        :show-dropdowns="true"
        v-model="ad_expire_date"
        class="form-control"
>
    <div slot="input" slot-scope="picker">
        {{ picker.startDate | date }}
    </div>
</date-range-picker>
```

Not to forhet set : before property name

Comment: just what the docs says in the brackets :)